What is the best way to repair this drywall?
A few years ago I removed some cabinets from this space, and at the time I used spackle that I had on hand to repair the wall.  I know this wasn't the right way to do it - it didn't quite lay flat, and it has always bothered me, so I decided to try it again.  Before I do, I thought I'd consult here for advice on the best way to do this.  Do I just use a few coats of joint compound, and texture at the end?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!


Unless it's a photo perspective issue, it looks to me like you have different textures on either side of that gap.  If so, matching may be an issue.

I'd be using a kitchen rubber spatula to apply the mud so just the damaged area get filled with it without damagingor smoothing out the texturing on both sides. You'll have to experiment with the texturing. You've got a rougher surface on the left and almost a paint roller / sponge dabbing orange peel surface on the right so matching will be a challange but the smaller the area, the less noticeable.

First of all, I’m pretty sure that’s plaster, maybe veneer plaster.
I’d probably prime it, then fill the first pass with quick set, slightly under level, and wet sponge the edges while wet. After it’s dry, skim it with passes of all purpose compound until it quits bubbling, letting dry between coats, then wet sand the edges into the texture. After this you can texture with roller or whatever you are going to do as the textures aren’t going to match without covering the whole wall.
If you want to match the sand texture, you could experiment with rolling or troweling mixed sand in your mud. It’s going to be hard to match the plaster sand finish using drywall finishing compounds.
